# For SEO, can I put an English title on a foreign language blog post?

Tags: seo, title, internationalization, language

I'm writing blog content by Japanese mainly. I think making the blog multi language for English is better idea for SEO. but I have no much time to write additional content with foreign languages.

I have an idea: I'd write only an English title tag and an article in another language.  For the English page, I'd use the English title but  all other content would be identical to the other language page.  That would be an efficient way to get traffic from foreign counties.

Is this good idea? or if not why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an idea: I'd write only an English title tag and an article in
>   another language. For the English page, I'd use the English title but
>   all other content would be identical to the other language page. That
>   would be an efficient way to get traffic from foreign counties.

Let me consider the following example. 
Someone created a web page with an article in Mongolian, but the name of the article was created in Arabic. Arabic-speaking user (not learning Mongolian) can see in the SERP title of the article and would pass on this web page. I doubt that this user could read the article in Mongolian. A Mongol-speaking user (who has not studied Arabic) would simply skip this article in the SIRP, which has a name in Arabic. Thus, this article is unlikely to attract high traffic, especially the traffic of targeted users who are looking for the subject of this article. When creating an article, this bilingualism may be deemed irrelevant or even misleading, as it could be with an Arabic-speaking user.

This also contradicts the following Google recommendation of **[Managing multi-regional and multilingual sites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192)**:

> Make sure the page language is obvious

Your idea probably doesn't make sense.